# Can I upload journal articles to a private git repo?

Tags: journals, copyright

I have some journal articles that are obviously copyrighted in some form that I am not allowed to share with people who don't have a license.

I also have a private student git-repo. I want to know if it's okay to upload these articles to the repo, considering the repo is private?

Comment: Yes? Can you store them in your personal hard drive? Have them in your personal email? Download them to your computer temporary memory for visualizing them on the internet browser? In all cases only you have access to it, thus the same rules applies. However, you may just be using git wrongly, as its not a data storage platform, its a version control platform

Comment: No legal issues since it's private, but I can't imagine why you would store journal articles in a repo.

Comment: @user3765080 I can see it if you have for example lectures and example code for a class in a repo that you might also store readings there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I store all important papers in a cloud, where I am the only one (beside the operating people) that has access. There are several such cloud solutions around, such as from DropBox, Microsoft and many others.
Unless there is an explicit statement that does not allow this, it is perfect (and until now, there has not been such a statement). The key is that you restrict access to yourself.
I would not use git for your case; it is intended for software development.

Answer (score 1):

I would see some use-case to store some papers in a git repo, mostly for convienience. That said, the use of `git-lfs`([git-lfs repo](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs)) should be prefered for pdf and other large non changing binary files (images, sounds) .